# XSL to transform XML to HTML, filter elements from multiple structures for the same element value

Tags: html, xml, xslt, transformation

I am a newcomer to XML/XSLT and, so far, in searching SO and the W3SChools sites for clever stuff on Meunchian grouping I haven't been able to grasp an effective solution to my challenge.

Essentially I have one large XML file exported from a database (which means I can't directly edit the XML) which contains invoicing information.

I want to utilise XSLT (1.0) to apply a transformation of the XML into HTML (I am using Saxon) so that each invoice is displayed as a table. However, in the XML, there are many product lines which relate to the same invoice (denoted by the `<invoiceNum>` element as the identifier).

I don't want to have to create & display a new table for each product line which is part of the same invoice. In my current XSL file, I am trying to create a table for the first instance of a duplicated `<invoiceNum>` element, and then add only the unique elements from successive product lines (`<ProductID>`, `<ProductName>`, `<ProductDescription>` etc.) and leave out the duplicated shipping information.

In the XML code snippet, you can see the layout of the XML. In the XSL snippet, I hope you can see how I am trying to construct the table. For each successive `<invoices_snet>` instance in the XML file, I want to add just the product information to the table through the transformation. Using `for-each` on the `<invoices_snet>` element simply creates a new table each time.

Should I use conditional logic here, compare the equality of the value of the `<invoices_snet>` element, use templates?

Your help is much appreciated!

```
 <database>
  <invoices>
   <invoices_snet>
    <invoiceNum NAME="invoiceNum" TYPE="SMALLINT">368</invoiceNum>
    <ProductID NAME="ProductID" TYPE="VARCHAR">SS106</ProductID>
    <ProductName NAME="ProductName" TYPE="VARCHAR">Senna  Sunglasses</ProductName>
    <ProductDescription NAME="ProductDescription" TYPE="VARCHAR">Lively sunglasses</ProductDescription>
    <Quantity NAME="Quantity" TYPE="SMALLINT">34</Quantity>
    <UnitPrice NAME="UnitPrice" TYPE="CURRENCY">40.0000</UnitPrice>
    <ExtendedPrice NAME="ExtendedPrice" TYPE="CURRENCY">1360.0000</ExtendedPrice>
    <contactName NAME="contactName" TYPE="VARCHAR">Jeff</contactName>
    <shippingStreet NAME="shippingStreet" TYPE="VARCHAR">11 Acacia Avenue</shippingStreet>
    <shippingCity NAME="shippingCity" TYPE="VARCHAR">Huddersfield</shippingCity>
    <shippingCounty NAME="shippingCounty" TYPE="VARCHAR">Yorkshire</shippingCounty>
    <shippingPostcode NAME="shippingPostcode" TYPE="VARCHAR">YO12 8LA</shippingPostcode>
    <saleDate NAME="salesDate" TYPE="DATETIME">30. Mar. 16</saleDate>
   </invoices_snet>
   <invoices_snet>
    <invoiceNum NAME="invoiceNum" TYPE="SMALLINT">368</invoiceNum>
    <ProductID NAME="ProductID" TYPE="VARCHAR">SS368</ProductID>
    <ProductName NAME="ProductName" TYPE="VARCHAR">Senna T-shirts</ProductName>
    <ProductDescription NAME="ProductDescription" TYPE="VARCHAR">T-shirts of beige colour with cream piping</ProductDescription>
    <Quantity NAME="Quantity" TYPE="SMALLINT">20</Quantity>
    <UnitPrice NAME="UnitPrice" TYPE="CURRENCY">15.00</UnitPrice>
    <ExtendedPrice NAME="ExtendedPrice" TYPE="CURRENCY">300.00</ExtendedPrice>
    <contactName NAME="contactName" TYPE="VARCHAR">Jeff</contactName>
    <shippingStreet NAME="shippingStreet" TYPE="VARCHAR">11 Acacia Avenue</shippingStreet>
    <shippingCity NAME="shippingCity" TYPE="VARCHAR">Huddersfield</shippingCity>
    <shippingCounty NAME="shippingCounty" TYPE="VARCHAR">Yorkshire</shippingCounty>
    <shippingPostcode NAME="shippingPostcode" TYPE="VARCHAR">YO12 8LA</shippingPostcode>
    <saleDate NAME="salesDate" TYPE="DATETIME">30. Mar. 16</saleDate>
   </invoices_snet>
  </invoices>
 </database>




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/database">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Invoice</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="invoicingCSS.css"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Invoice</h1>
                <br></br>
                <xsl:for-each select="invoices/invoices_snet">
                <h2>Order for Invoice Number: <xsl:value-of select="invoiceNum"/> </h2>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product ID</th>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Product Description</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Unit Price</th>
                        <th>Extended Price</th>
                        <th>Contact Name</th>
                        <th>Shipping Address</th>
                        <th>Sales Date</th>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="ProductID"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="ProductName"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="ProductDescription"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="UnitPrice"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="ExtendedPrice"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="contactName"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat(
                                                    shippingStreet,' ',
                                                    shippingCity,', ',
                                                    shippingCounty,', ',
                                                    shippingPostcode)" 
                                />
                            </td>                            
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="saleDate"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: **1.** Are the lines sorted by invoiceNum? **2.** If you are using Saxon, why do you limit yourself to XSLT 1.0? -- **P.S.** This is a grouping problem - there are **many** examples you can find here.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your input! 1. Yes, the idea is that the value of the invoiceNum element would serve as the unique identifier (it has a one to many relationship with ProductID, ProductName, ProductDescription etc.). I haven't applied any sorting, the XML file is just in the state which has come extraction from the database. 2. I am just beginning with XML and XSL, so I hadn't though to need some of the 2.0 features yet; no harm to change that though. Grouping? OK, will focus my searching efforts on those problems, as you mention...

Comment: Hm I would not change to XSLT 2.0 if there is not a bigger reason then this small grouping issue. With 1.0 you have a loot more possible xslt processors e.g. xsltproc or even in browser. I do not know any browser supporting XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @user6196074 Is your question not answered?

Comment: Yes, @michael.hor257k, I managed to construct a working solution based on the pointers you graciously gave in your answer; thanks again!  In the end a specific XSLT version wasn't demanded so I found 2.0 easier to execute with grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping is **much** easier to do in XSLT 2.0, with its built-in `xsl:for-each-group` instruction.

Try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="theader">
    <tr>
        <th>ProductID</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <!-- add more as required -->
    </tr>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/database">
    <html>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="invoices/invoices_snet" group-by="invoiceNum">
            <table border="1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$theader"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </table>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="invoices_snet">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="ProductID"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/>
        </td>
        <!-- add more as required -->
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

<xsl:template match="invoices_snet">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="ProductID"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

First do you self a favor and have a look for xslt grouping for XSLT 1.0 this will be **muenchian grouping** e.g. [this](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)

And here the basic structure for a adaption to your xml:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <xsl:key name="kinvoices_snet" match="invoices_snet" use="invoiceNum"/>
  <xsl:template match="invoices">
    <xsl:for-each select="invoices_snet [ 
                            count ( key('kinvoices_snet',./invoiceNum)[1] | . ) = 1 ]">

      <xsl:variable name="this" select="." />
      <g>
        <gh>
          <xsl:value-of select="invoiceNum" />
        </gh>
        <!-- group stuff -->

         <xsl:for-each select=" key('kinvoices_snet',$this/invoiceNum)">
           <!-- group member stuff -->
           <gm>
                <xsl:value-of select="ProductID" />
           </gm>
         </xsl:for-each>  
      </g>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```